# Randomly Generating Curved/Wavy Paths

Tags: algorithm, canvas, path, html5-canvas

I have a massive image of a map that is much larger than the viewport and centered in the viewport, which can be explored by the user by dragging the screen. In order to create a parallax effect, I used a massive image of clouds in the foreground. As the user explores the map via dragging, both the background and foreground move in a parallax fashion. So far, so good.

However, what I really want to do is give the image of clouds a "default" movement that would be randomly generated on each page load, so that the clouds would always be moving, even if the user is not dragging. I know this can be done by animating the foreground along a path, but I am not exactly sure how to go about this.

How can I randomly generate ***irregularly curved*** or ***wavy*** paths on each page load?

Does anybody know of any algorithms that can do this?

Comment: You could use some random walk with random drift like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process with a coarse, large step approximation, and use cubic patches to interpolate to get a somewhat smooth path.

Comment: @LutzL interesting!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also use a copy of the previous answers to realize a simplified version of what  I hinted at in the comments.

Use a random walk on the unit circle, that is on the angle, to determine a velocity vector that slowly but randomly changes and move forward using cubic Bezier patches.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 600;
var ch = c.height = 400;
var cx = cw / 4, cy = ch / 2;

var angVel = v.value;
var tension = t.value;
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

var npts = 60;
var dw = Array();
var xs = Array();
var ys = Array();
var vxs = Array();
var vys = Array();

function Randomize() {
    for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
        dw[i] = (2*Math.random()-1);
    }
}

function ComputePath() {
    xs[0]=cx; ys[0]=cy; 
    var angle = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
        vxs[i]=10*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*angle);
        vys[i]=10*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*angle);
        angle = angle + dw[i]*angVel;
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < npts; i++) {
        xs[i] = xs[i-1]+3*(vxs[i-1]+vxs[i])/2; 
        ys[i] = ys[i-1]+3*(vys[i-1]+vys[i])/2;
    }
}

function Draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xs[0],ys[0]); 
  for (var i = 1; i < npts; i++) {
    var cp1x = xs[i-1]+tension*vxs[i-1];
    var cp1y = ys[i-1]+tension*vys[i-1];
    var cp2x = xs[i]-tension*vxs[i];
    var cp2y = ys[i]-tension*vys[i]
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, xs[i], ys[i]); 
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
Randomize();
ComputePath();
Draw();

r.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  Randomize();
  ComputePath();
  Draw();
})

v.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  angVel = v.value;
  vlabel.innerHTML = ""+angVel;
  ComputePath();
  Draw();
})

t.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  tension = t.value;
  tlabel.innerHTML = ""+tension;
  Draw();
})
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id = 'c'></canvas>
<table>
  <tr><td>angular velocity:</td><td> <input type="range" id="v" min ="0" max = "0.5" step = "0.01" value="0.2" /></td><td id="vlabel"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>tension</td><td> <input type="range" id="t" min ="0" max = "1" step = "0.1" value="0.8" /></td><td id="tlabel"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>remix</td><td> <button id="r"> + </button></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This random walk part on the unit circle is very nice.

Comment: interesting approach!!

Comment: hey would u mind taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164738/dynamic-wavy-path-border) if u dont mind

Answer (score 5):

I was impressed by the functionality to be able to draw canvases in the SO answers, so I "stole" *enxaneta* code snippet and played a bit with it (hope that is ok).

The idea is to generate several random points `(xs, ys)` and for each `x` from the path to interpolate the y as `y = sum{ys_i*w_i}/sum{w_i}`, where `w_i` is some interpolation weight as a function of `x`. For example `w_i(x) = (xs_i - x)^(-2)`. Hope this makes sense - if this is of any interested I'll try to provide more details.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 600;
var ch = c.height = 150;
var cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2;

var amplitude = a.value;
var frequency = f.value;
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

var npts = 20;
var xs = Array();
var ys = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
   xs[i] = (cw/npts)*i; 
   ys[i] = 2.0*(Math.random()-0.5)*amplitude;
}

function Draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
 
  for (var x = 0; x < cw; x++) {
    y = 0.0;
    wsum = 0.0;
    for (var i = -5; i <= 5; i++) {
       xx = x;
       ii = Math.round(x/xs[1]) + i;
       if (ii < 0) { xx += cw; ii += npts; }
       if (ii >= npts) { xx -= cw; ii -= npts; }
       w = Math.abs(xs[ii] - xx);
       w = Math.pow(w, frequency); 
       y += w*ys[ii];
       wsum += w;
    }
    y /= wsum;
    //y = Math.sin(x * frequency) * amplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+cy); 
  }

  ctx.stroke();

}
Draw();

a.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  amplitude = a.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
    xs[i] = (cw/npts)*i; 
    ys[i] = 2.0*(Math.random()-0.5)*amplitude;
  }
  Draw();
})

f.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  frequency = f.value;
  Draw();
})
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id = 'c'></canvas>
<p>amplitude: <input type="range" id="a" min ="1" max = "100"  value="50" /></p>
<p>frequency: <input type="range" id="f" min ="-10" max = "1" step = "0.1" value="-2" hidden/></p>
```

Comment: something like this is exactly what im looking for. it would be even better if you had the option to join the ends of the path to make it a closed circuit so to speak

Comment: @Anthony I have edited the code in order to achieve this effect. The idea is to make the buffer of random points circular and interpolate just the nearby points, accounting for the circularity of the `xs` array. Now the two ends of the path have the same Y coordinate and the path at these boundary points is smooth.

Comment: dope. im going to try implementing this tomorrow~ thx so much georgi!!

Comment: would u mind taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164738/dynamic-wavy-path-border)

Answer (score 4):

If your question is: *How can I randomly generate curved or wavy paths?* this is how I would do it: I'm using inputs type range to change the value for `amplitude` and `frequency`, but you can set those values randomly on load. 
I hope it helps.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 800;
var ch = c.height = 150;
var cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2;

var amplitude = a.value;
var frequency = f.value;
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

function Draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
 
  for (var x = 0; x < cw; x++) {
    y = Math.sin(x * frequency) * amplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+cy); 
  }

  ctx.stroke();

}
Draw();

a.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  amplitude = a.value;
  Draw();
})

f.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  frequency = f.value;
  Draw();
})
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id = 'c'></canvas>
<p>frequency: <input type="range" id="f" min ="0.01" max = "0.1" step = "0.001" value=".05" /></p>
<p>amplitude: <input type="range" id="a" min ="1" max = "100"  value="50" /></p>
```

Comment: thanks, but i was hoping for irregular curves/waves. sorry, i should have specified that

Answer (score 4):

## Deterministic random paths

Storing paths for random movement is not needed. Random is like having very complex behaviour, and for humans it does not take much complexity to make something look random.

Thus with a little randomness, added to complexity you can easily give the appearance of the infinite non repeating sequence which can be rewound, stopped, slowed down, speed up, etc. Its fully deterministic and requires only a single value to store (the ultimate compression if you ignore the generating code).

### Complex cycles.

To move a point in a circle around a center you can use sin and cos.

For example a point `x,y` and you want to move in a ball around that point at a distance of `dist` and a rate once a second. Example in snippet.

```js
var px = 100; // point of rotation.
var py = 100;
const RPS = 1; // Rotations Per Second
const dist = 50; // distance from point
const radius = 25; // circle radius

function moveObj(time) { // Find rotated point and draw    
    time = (time / 1000) * PI2 *  RPS;  // convert the time to rotations per secon    
    const xx = Math.cos(time) * dist;
    const yy = Math.sin(time) * dist;       
    drawCircle(xx, yy) 
}






// Helpers
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
function drawCircle(x,y,r = radius) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,px,py);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,PI2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);    
    moveObj(time);         
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
const PI = Math.PI;
const PI2 = PI * 2;
```

```css
canvas {
   background : #8AF;
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Next let's move the point around which we rotate, using the method above.
Then for the ball we can change the phase of the rotation in x from the rotation in y. This means that the ball rotating around the now rotating point, and the balls rotating axis are out of phase.

The result is a more complex movements.

```js
var px = 100; // point of rotation.
var py = 100;
const RPS_P = 0.1; // point Rotations Per Second 0.1 every 10 seconds
const RPS_X = 1; // Rotations Per Second in x axis of circle
const RPS_Y = 0.8; // Rotations Per Second in y axis of circle
const dist_P = 30; // distance from center point is
const dist = 50; // distance from point
const radius = 25; // circle radius

function moveObj(time) { // Find rotated point and draw    
    var phaseX = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_X;
    var phaseY = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_Y;
    const xx = Math.cos(phaseX) * dist;
    const yy = Math.sin(phaseY) * dist;       
    drawCircle(xx, yy) 
}

function movePoint(time) { // move point around center
    time = (time / 1000) * PI2 *  RPS_P; 
    px = 100 + Math.cos(time) * dist_P;
    py = 100 + Math.sin(time) * dist_P;       
 
}


// Helpers
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
function drawCircle(x,y,r = radius) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,px,py);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,PI2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);    
    movePoint(time);
    moveObj(time);         
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
const PI = Math.PI;
const PI2 = PI * 2;
```

```css
canvas {
   background : #8AF;
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

We can continue to add out of phase rotations. In the next example we now rotate the rotation point around the center, add out of phase rotation to that point and finally draw the ball with its out of phase rotation.

```js
var px = 100; // point of rotation.
var py = 100;
const RPS_C_X = 0.43; // Rotation speed X of rotating rotation  point
const RPS_C_Y = 0.47; // Rotation speed Y of rotating rotation  point
const RPS_P_X = 0.093; // point Rotations speed X
const RPS_P_Y = 0.097; // point Rotations speed Y
const RPS_X = 1; // Rotations Per Second in x axis of circle
const RPS_Y = 0.8; // Rotations Per Second in y axis of circle
const dist_C = 20; // distance from center point is
const dist_P = 30; // distance from center point is
const dist = 30; // distance from point
const radius = 25; // circle radius

function moveObj(time) { // Find rotated point and draw    
    var phaseX = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_X;
    var phaseY = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_Y;
    const xx = Math.cos(phaseX) * dist;
    const yy = Math.sin(phaseY) * dist;       
    drawCircle(xx, yy) 
}

function movePoints(time) { // Move the rotating pointe and rotate the rotation point 
                            // around that point

    var phaseX = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_C_X;
    var phaseY = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_C_Y;
    px = 100 + Math.cos(phaseX) * dist_C;
    py = 100 + Math.sin(phaseY) * dist_C;  

    phaseX = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_P_X;
    phaseY = (time / 1000) * PI2 * RPS_P_Y;
    px = px + Math.cos(phaseX) * dist_P;
    py = py + Math.sin(phaseY) * dist_P;       
 
}


// Helpers
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
function drawCircle(x,y,r = radius) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,px,py);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,PI2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);    
    movePoints(time);
    moveObj(time);         
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
const PI = Math.PI;
const PI2 = PI * 2;
```

```css
canvas {
   background : #8AF;
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

So now we have a very complex rotation. The position is a function of time, you can repeat the movement by just setting the time back to the start. You don't need to store a long complex path.

### Add a little random

You may see some repeating movement but if you use primes to set each rotation rate the repeating pattern will cycle as a product of the primes (Most people will not be able to tell when the repeat is if you use big even small primes).

If you want many objects each with a different movement you can randomise, rotation rates and any other property you may want.

### Seeded Random

Javascript does not have a seeded random generator. However you can create one.

The next snippet shows a basic random generator

```
const seededRandom = (() => {
  var seed = 1;
  return { 
    max : 2576436549074795, 
    reseed (s) { 
      seed = s; 
    }, 
    random ()  { 
      return seed = ((8765432352450986 * seed) + 8507698654323524) % this.max; 
    }
  };
})();
```

`seededRandom.random()` returns a random integer from 0 to `seededRandom.max - 1`.

`seededRandom.random() / seededRandom.max` returns a random double from  0 to 1 (non-inclusive of 1).

Each seed creates a repeatable unique sequence of random values.

It's not perfect (don't use it to encrypt sensitive data, simulate real-world randomness, make a slot machine) but it's more than adequate for visual / behavioural randomness

With a seeded random generator you can use the seed to generate a random objects.

Using the same seed again you get the same object. In the example below I use a seed from 0 to 10000000 to create a cloud. That means there are 10000000 unique repeatable clouds.

### Example of deterministic random clouds

Using all the methods outlined above and the same `seededRandom` object the following is an example of a repeatable seeded squequence.

Restart and it will repeat exactly the same. To change it to non deterministic random just add `randSeed(Math.random() * 100000 | 0)`

```js
const seededRandom = (() => {
    var seed = 1;
    return { max : 2576436549074795, reseed (s) { seed = s }, random ()  { return seed = ((8765432352450986 * seed) + 8507698654323524) % this.max }}
})();
const randSeed = (seed) => seededRandom.reseed(seed|0);
const randSI = (min = 2, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seededRandom.random() % (max - min)) + min;
const randS  = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seededRandom.random() / seededRandom.max) * (max - min) + min;
const randSPow  = (min, max = min + (min = 0), p = 2) => (max + min) / 2 + (Math.pow(seededRandom.random() / seededRandom.max, p) * (max - min) * 0.5) * (randSI(2) < 1 ? 1 : -1);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const W = ctx.canvas.width;
const H = ctx.canvas.height;
const DIAG = (W * W + H * H) ** 0.5;
const colors = {
    dark : {
        minRGB : [100 * 0.6,200 * 0.6,240 * 0.6],
        maxRGB : [255 * 0.6,255 * 0.6,255 * 0.6],
    },
    light : {
        minRGB : [100,200,240],
        maxRGB : [255,255,255],
    },
}
const getCol = (pos, range) => "rgba(" +
    ((range.maxRGB[0] - range.minRGB[0]) * pos + range.minRGB[0] | 0) + "," + 
    ((range.maxRGB[1] - range.minRGB[1]) * pos + range.minRGB[1] | 0) + "," + 
    ((range.maxRGB[2] - range.minRGB[2]) * pos + range.minRGB[2] | 0) + "," +(pos * 0.2 + 0.8) + ")";


const Cloud = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    dir : 0, // in radians
    wobble : 0,
    wobble1 : 0,
    wSpeed : 0,
    wSpeed1 : 0,
    mx : 0,  // Move offsets
    my : 0,
    seed : 0,
    size : 2, 
    detail : null,
    reset : true, // when true could resets
    init() {
        this.seed = randSI(10000000);
        this.reset = false;
        var x,y,r,dir,dist,f;
        if (this.detail === null) { this.detail = [] }
        else { this.detail.length = 0 }
        randSeed(this.seed);
        this.size = randSPow(2, 8);  // The pow add bias to smaller values
        var col = (this.size -2) / 6;
        this.col1 = getCol(col,colors.dark)
        this.col2 = getCol(col,colors.light)
        var flufCount = randSI(5,15);
        while (flufCount--) {
            x = randSI(-this.size * 8, this.size * 8);
            r = randS(this.size * 2, this.size * 8);
            dir = randS(Math.PI * 2);
            dist = randSPow(1) * r ;
            this.detail.push(f = {x,r,y : 0,mx:0,my:0, move : randS(0.001,0.01), phase : randS(Math.PI * 2)});
            f.x+= Math.cos(dir) * dist;
            f.y+= Math.sin(dir) * dist;

        }
        this.xMax = this.size * 12 + this.size * 10 + this.size * 4;
        this.yMax = this.size * 10 + this.size * 4;
        this.wobble = randS(Math.PI * 2);
        this.wSpeed = randS(0.01,0.02);
        this.wSpeed1 = randS(0.01,0.02);
        const aOff = randS(1) * Math.PI * 0.5 - Math.PI *0.25;
        this.x = W / 2 - Math.cos(this.dir+aOff) * DIAG * 0.7;
        this.y = H / 2 - Math.sin(this.dir+aOff) * DIAG * 0.7;
        clouds.sortMe = true; // flag that coulds need resort
    },
    move() {
        var dx,dy;
        this.dir = gTime / 10000;
        if(this.reset) { this.init() }
        this.wobble += this.wSpeed;
        this.wobble1 += this.wSpeed1;
        this.mx = Math.cos(this.wobble) * this.size * 4;
        this.my = Math.sin(this.wobble1) * this.size * 4;
        this.x += dx = Math.cos(this.dir) * this.size / 5;
        this.y += dy = Math.sin(this.dir) * this.size / 5;
        if (dx > 0 && this.x > W + this.xMax ) { this.reset = true }
        else if (dx < 0 && this.x < - this.xMax ) { this.reset = true }
        if (dy > 0 && this.y > H + this.yMax) { this.reset = true }
        else if (dy < 0 && this.y < - this.yMax) { this.reset = true }

        
    },
    draw(){
        const s = this.size;
        const s8 = this.size * 8;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col1;
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,this.x+ this.mx,this.y +this.my);
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const fluf of this.detail) {
            fluf.phase += fluf.move + Math.sin(this.wobble * this.wSpeed1) * 0.02 *  Math.cos(fluf.phase);
            fluf.mx = Math.cos(fluf.phase) * fluf.r / 2;
            fluf.my = Math.sin(fluf.phase) * fluf.r / 2;
            const x = fluf.x + fluf.mx;
            const y = fluf.y + fluf.my;
            ctx.moveTo(x + fluf.r + s, y);
            ctx.arc(x,y,fluf.r+ s,0,Math.PI * 2);
        }
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col2;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const fluf of this.detail) {
            const x = fluf.x + fluf.mx - s;
            const y = fluf.y + fluf.my - s;
            ctx.moveTo(x + fluf.r, y);
            ctx.arc(x,y,fluf.r,0,Math.PI * 2);
        }
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const fluf of this.detail) {
            const x = fluf.x + fluf.mx - s * 1.4;
            const y = fluf.y + fluf.my - s * 1.4;
            ctx.moveTo(x + fluf.r * 0.8, y);
            ctx.arc(x,y,fluf.r* 0.8,0,Math.PI * 2);
        }
        ctx.fill();        
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    }
}

function createCloud(size){ return {...Cloud} }

const clouds = Object.assign([],{
    move() { for(const cloud of this){ cloud.move() } },
    draw() { for(const cloud of this){ cloud.draw() } },
    sortMe : true, // if true then needs to resort
    resort() { 
        this.sortMe = false;
        this.sort((a,b)=>a.size - b.size);
    }
});
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i ++) { clouds.push(createCloud(40)) }
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
var gTime = 0;
function mainLoop() {
    gTime += 16;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if(clouds.sortMe) { clouds.resort() }
    clouds.move();
    clouds.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

}
```

```css
body { padding : 0px; margin : 0px;}
canvas {
   background : rgb(60,120,148);
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: this is ingenious. what a unique and eloquent approach.