# Dynamic Wavy Path/Border

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, dynamic

There is something I need to build, but my math ability is not up to par. What I am looking to build is something like [this demo,](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-colorful-wave-effect/) but I need it to be a hybrid of a circle and polygon instead of a line, so to speak. The black line should be dynamic and randomly generated that basically acts as a border on the page.

Currently, I am dissecting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54051068/7543162) with the aim of hopefully being able to transpose it into this, but I am having massive doubts that I will be able to figure this out.

[image]

**Any idea how to do this or can anybody explain the mathematics?**

Below are my notes about the code from the answer I linked above.

```
var
  cw = cvs.width = window.innerWidth,
  ch = cvs.height = window.innerHeight,
  cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2,
  xs = Array(),
  ys = Array(),
  npts = 20,
  amplitude = 87, // can be val from 1 to 100
  frequency = -2, // can be val from -10 to 1 in steps of 0.1

ctx.lineWidth = 4

// creates array of coordinates that
// divides page into regular portions
// creates array of weights
for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
  xs[i] = (cw/npts)*i
  ys[i] = 2.0*(Math.random()-0.5)*amplitude
}

function Draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (let x = 0; x < cw; x++) {
    y = 0.0
    wsum = 0.0

    for (let i = -5; i <= 5; i++) {
      xx = x; // 0 / 1 / 2 / to value of screen width

      // creates sequential sets from [-5 to 5] to [15 to 25]
      ii = Math.round(x/xs[1]) + i

      // `xx` is a sliding range with the total value equal to client width
      // keeps `ii` within range of 0 to 20
      if (ii < 0) {
        xx += cw
        ii += npts
      }
      if (ii >= npts){
        xx -= cw
        ii -= npts
      }

      // selects eleven sequential array items
      // which are portions of the screen width and height
      // to create staggered inclines in increments of those portions
      w = Math.abs(xs[ii] - xx)

      // creates irregular arcs
      // based on the inclining values
      w = Math.pow(w, frequency)

      // also creates irregular arcs therefrom
      y += w*ys[ii];

      // creates sets of inclining values
      wsum += w;

    }

    // provides a relative position or weight
    // for each y-coordinate in the total path
    y /= wsum;

    //y = Math.sin(x * frequency) * amplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+cy); 
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
Draw();
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the shape? Is some path given that the wavy one should roughly follow?

Comment: @LutzL it should be a rough approximation of a rectangle (or whatever the `clientWidth` of the screen happens to be). it should almost be like a border around the page. it's supposed to represent a fog of war like in a video game. but i'd like to make the wavy lines dynamic and it would also be nice to be able to adjust the thickness of the green part or in other words shrink the "rectangle" visible area.

Comment: @LutzL kind of like a border, but wavy along the inside edge instead of straight lines. [kind of like this.](https://i.postimg.cc/zfDP4GWT/fogofwar.png), but maybe a bit more wavy. i plan to make the waves dynamic and also i plan to make it opaque around the outer edges and then fade to transparency the closer you get to the center. i gtg to bed but i'll check back tomo <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my answer. Please read the comments in the code. I hope this is what you need.

```js
// initiate the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// define the corners of an rectangle
let corners = [[100, 100], [500, 100], [500, 300], [100, 300]];

let amplitud = 20;// oscilation amplitude
let speed = 0.01;// the speed of the oscilation
let points = []; // an array of points to draw the curve

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // the point is oscilating around this point (cx,cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // the current angle of oscilation
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// a variable to know if the oscilation is horizontal or vertical

    this.update();
  }

  // a function to update the value of the angle
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// a function to divide a line that goes from a to b in n segments
// I'm using the resulting points to create a new point object and push this new point into the points array
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();


// this is a function that takes an array of points and draw a curved line through those points
function drawCurves() {
  //find the first midpoint and move to it
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //curve through the rest, stopping at each midpoint
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //curve through the last point, back to the first midpoint
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:#6ab150}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: perfect. thank you sooooooooooooooo much <33 now time for me to go through the code to understand how you did this!!

Comment: i have yet to look over all of the code myself, but is there any way to apply a gradient, so that the dynamic inner edge of the green part where it meets the white part is always transparent and the very outside is completely green, so that in other words, say, the half of the green area on the inside is always translucent? does that make sense?

Comment: In the demo there is a canvas with a green background and a waving shape with a white fill. You can change the fill style for the shape to a gradient but I'm afraid this is not what you want. Please take a look at this pen: [Aquarelle Animation](https://codepen.io/leusrox/pen/Xaadrx) Maybe this is what you need.

Comment: @enxaneta Great answer! Always interested in your answers.

Comment: ya thats kinda what im talking about. where instead of the fog of war border having solid edges, it seeps into the middle. i know i could make something similar stacking layers and or perhaps using a mask like in that demo and just animating the position of the mask. itd probably be the simplest way

Comment: hey can u point me towards any info (e.g. articles, demos, etc) of generating random waves (on load) that seep down the screen like goo? or at least articles to help me understand the mathematics of creating waves?